# How to hint that a flutter widget is scrollable?

Tags: flutter

For Flutter SingleChildScrollView, ListView and many other views, it can happen that the initial display has elements that exactly line up with the containing display, with no partially shown widgets. In this case, the UI provides no clue to the user that the view is scrollable at the scrollable contents may look 'complete' to the user.

Is there a Flutter pattern to provide UI feedback to indicate that the view is scrollable (it probably shouldn't provide that hint if the scrollview is fully viewed and is therefore not scrollable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try wrapping your scrollable widget with a [Scrollbar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html)

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        ....
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use the `isAlwaysShown` property to make sure the indicator is always active.

By default, it is draggable on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may use the Scrollbar widget.

> **Scrollbar class**
>
> A material design scrollbar.
>
> A scrollbar indicates which portion of a Scrollable widget is actually
> visible.
>
> Dynamically changes to an iOS style scrollbar that looks like
> CupertinoScrollbar on the iOS platform.
>
> To add a scrollbar to a ScrollView, simply wrap the scroll view widget
> in a Scrollbar widget.

2. You may also use package such as **[draggable_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar)**

> **Draggable Scrollbar**
>
> A scrollbar that can be dragged for quickly navigation through a
> vertical list. Additionaly it can show label next to scrollthumb with
> information about current item, for example date of picture created